# Possible to delay component rendering with `onEnter`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router

I am using the React Router `onEnter` attribute to handle authentication, like below, and also as demonstrated in the ["auth-flow" example](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/examples/auth-flow/app.js#L135).

```
   function requireAuth(nextState, replace, next) {
     Auth.validateToken()
       .then(() =>  {
         next();
       })
       .fail(() => {
         replace('/login');
         next();
       }); 
   }

   <Router history={history}>
      <Route path="/" component={App} >
        <IndexRoute
          component={Dashboard}
          onEnter={requireAuth}
        />
        <Route
          path="login"
          component={LogInForm}
        />
      </Route>
    </Router>
```

I am using the asynchronous callback functionality of `onEnter` because my token validation requires a server call.

The problem I am experiencing is that the `Dashboard` component in this example renders/mounts before `next()` is called. Ideally, rendering would wait until the callback is fired.

Am I misunderstanding how this is intended to work? Is there a way to delay rendering of route components until certain conditions are true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't ever delay route rendering, your users deserve better.

There is absolutely a different way to do this, and that's by having the actual page you render contain the logic for seeing if someone's authorized to view it, with a starting `state` that has soemthing like `authorized: false`, and that your callback switches using `this.setState({ authorized: resultFromCallback })`.

That state change will cause React to call `render()` again on your page, *if the value was different*, and then in your page's `render()` function you simply check `this.state.authorized` to see whether you should present the user with a UI that contains all the bits they should see as anonymous user, or all the bits they should see as authorized user.

```
...
  componentDidount() {
    whateverlib.checkForAuthorization(this.handleAuthorization);
  },
  handleAuthorization(authorized) {
    this.setState({ authorized });
  },
  render() {
    if(this.state.authorized) {
      return this.renderAuthorizedUI();
    }
    return this.renderAnonymousUI();
  },
...
```

Also remember that your app is still *just JavaScript running on a webpage*, so why would you even check for every page you load? All you need to do is check on any page, store that result, and done. As long as the user keeps their tab open, their authorization state does not spontaneously change from one react-router app-managed page to the next, so you can use an app-global tracker.

```
var authorizer = require('./lib/whatever-thing-you-wrote-for-this');

var YourPage = React.createClass({
  ...
  componentDidMount() {
    if (!authorizer.isAuthorized()) {
      authorizer.tryAuthorize(this.handleAuthorization);
    }
  },
  handleAuthorization() {
    this.forceUpdate();
  },
  render() {
    if(authorizer.isAuthorized()) {
      return this.renderAuthorizedUI();
    }
    return this.renderAnonymousUI();
  },
  ...
});
```

Comment: These are really great thoughts, thank you! Still, however, it feels like this should be handled more in a "redirection" kinda way. Do you not think an unauthorized user's browser should be redirected to something like `/login`?

Comment: I do not. URLs are meant to be stable units of resource on the internet (web or otherwise), magically changing a link someone thinks they're following breaks that expectation *and* annoys your user. Instead, render the page they wanted but go "you are not signed in. Here's the login form. Right here, no need to click anywhere else, just fill this in, hit sign in, and without even needing to reload the page you'll get to the content you were looking for". Yes, you should have a dedicated `/login` route that your users can explicitly call, but you should not need to redirect to it. It's React.

Comment: To elaborate on "it's React": your login page should reasonably use a modular component to handle the signing in - simply also use that component on other pages when the user is not authorized yet, and done. The sign in component can house all the authorization code, and you can simply bootstrap it with an `onAuthorized={authorized => this.setState({ authorized })}` property to ensure it automatically does the right thing for any page that loads it into its UI.